# Framework Phaser, sumar solo una unidad con detección de colisión

Tags: javascript, typescript, poo, motor-de-juego, phaser

mi pregunta es sobre Phaser, tengo un problema con una etapa de un juego y no veo como puede lograrse.

Bueno, os comento el problema, tengo un sprite en forma de vehiculo, en un juego, que tiene que recoger una muestra, para eso se ha añadido un sprite con detección de borde, os paso el código de parte de la función create:

```
    this.iconoMuestra1 = this.physics.add.sprite(440, 500, 'sample');
    this.iconoMuestra2 = this.physics.add.sprite(600, 450, 'sample');
    this.iconoMuestra3 = this.physics.add.sprite(40, 40, 'sample');
    this.iconoMuestra4 = this.physics.add.sprite(700, 50, 'sample');
```

A continuación os paso donde se han creado la anchura y altura de los sprites:

```
    this.iconoMuestra1.displayWidth = 20;
    this.iconoMuestra1.displayHeight = 20;
    this.iconoMuestra2.displayWidth = 20;
    this.iconoMuestra2.displayHeight = 20;
    this.iconoMuestra3.displayWidth =20;
    this.iconoMuestra3.displayHeight = 20;
    this.iconoMuestra4.displayWidth = 20;
    this.iconoMuestra4.displayHeight = 20;
```

función que detecta colisión entre el vehículo y la muestra

```
collisionListenerBetweenSampleAndJeep() {
    this.physics.add.collider(
        this.iconoMuestra1,
        this.jeep1.sprite,
        this.CollectsampleHit,
        null,
        this);

    this.physics.add.collider(
        this.iconoMuestra2,
        this.jeep1.sprite,
        this.CollectsampleHit,
        null,
        this);
    this.physics.add.collider(
        this.iconoMuestra3,
        this.jeep1.sprite,
        this.CollectsampleHit,
        null,
        this);
    this.physics.add.collider(
        this.iconoMuestra4,
        this.jeep1.sprite,
        this.CollectsampleHit,
        null,
        this);

}
```

Esta es la función que hace que la muestra desaparezca y que suma una unidad a la variable contador mientras está en contacto.

```
 CollectsampleHit(sample, jeep) {
    sample.visible = false;
    this.contador++;

   this.display.message(`${this.contador}Contador`);

}
```

El problema que tengo es el siguiente: quisiera que solo sumara 1 unidad, no que estuviera continuamente sumando, la idea es que el dibujo del icono desaparece, pero al colisionar con el sitio donde estaba el icono continua sumando unidades, y solo quiero que sume una unidad.

De alguna forma lo que quiero es similar a cuando un muñeco salta, gana una moneda, se suman x puntos y ya en esa posición no queda objeto ni detector de colisión, y esa parte no logro sacarla en claro.

Answer (score 0):

Lo he arreglado, realmente no era importante sumar, sino recolectar las muestras, así que he añadido una función que comprueba si el icono es visible en las cuatro zonas, es decir, una booleana; Os paso el código.

```
CollectsampleHit(sample, jeep) {
   sample.visible = false;
   this.Comprobar();

}
Comprobar(){
    if(this.iconoMuestra1.visible==false&&this.iconoMuestra2.visible==false
        &&this.iconoMuestra3.visible==false&&this.iconoMuestra4.visible==false){
            this.display.message(`all Samples Collected, return to base`); 
        }
}
```